# cross validation vs shuffling

Tags: classification, cross-validation

I have a classifier. when I shuffle input data (a few times), make training/test data and run classifier, the accuracy is high but when I use cross validation in sklearn it drops by 15% (both recall and precision). Wondering what is the problem? and how to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure I understand your approach. Do you shuffle+train+test several times (ok) or do you shuffle several times and then train+test once (not ok)?

Assuming you do the first: the estimate of generalization performance you get this way will have higher variability than CV-accuracy because you use less data to test. Even if the measured accuracy appears to be higher, it is a worse estimate of generalization performance than CV-accuracy. I recommend sticking with CV.

Additionally, make sure that you have no information leak, e.g. training instances reappearing in your test set due to improper splitting. If the accuracy you obtain with your approach is consistently higher than the CV-accuracy, this may well be the reason.

Comment: Forgot to say: I use RandomForest with Out-of-Bag. I have seen some posts saying that Cross-Validation is not needed for this classifier. Don't understand CC for parameter estimation or CC for accuracy testing.

Comment: @BigDataLover:  have seen some posts saying that Cross-Validation is not needed for [random Forest]. => depends on your data: all random Forest implementation I know assume that the rows are independent of each other. If they are, the rF's internal oob estimate is OK. If not, you need to do your own validation to test with independent data.